# SWF (Flex created) In JSP

Tags: jsp, flex3

I created a Flex project, now I want to import it into the JSP, so I have just taken the 'noscript' section and have added to my jsp.

But the porblem is that the swf file does not play, any help?

Here is the piece of code

```
<noscript>
       <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
               id="TeamStructure" width="100%" height="100%"
               codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
               <param name="movie" value="TeamStructure.swf" />
               <param name="quality" value="high" />
               <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
               <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
               <embed src="TeamStructure.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                    width="100%" height="100%" name="TeamStructure" align="middle"
                    play="true"
                    loop="false"
                    quality="high"
                    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
               </embed>
     </object>
</noscript>
```

All the paths and other stuff have been validated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think flex generates an html page, and you should just copy-paste. Here's something that's working:

```
<div id="flexHolder">
<script src="AC_OETags.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script src="history/history.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var requiredMajorVersion = 9;
var requiredMinorVersion = 0;
var requiredRevision = 28;
-->
</script>

<iframe src="history/historyFrame.html" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Version check for the Flash Player that has the ability to start Player Product Install (6.0r65)
var hasProductInstall = DetectFlashVer(6, 0, 65);

// Version check based upon the values defined in globals
var hasRequestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);

if ( hasProductInstall && !hasRequestedVersion ) {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE FOLLOWING FOUR LINES
    // Location visited after installation is complete if installation is required
    var MMPlayerType = (isIE == true) ? "ActiveX" : "PlugIn";
    var MMredirectURL = window.location;
    document.title = document.title.slice(0, 47) + " - Flash Player Installation";
    var MMdoctitle = document.title;

    AC_FL_RunContent(
        "src", "playerProductInstall",
        "FlashVars", "MMredirectURL="+MMredirectURL+'&MMplayerType='+MMPlayerType+'&MMdoctitle='+MMdoctitle+"",
        "width", "800",
        "height", "540",
        "align", "middle",
        "id", "TeamStructure",
        "quality", "high",
        "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF",
        "name", "TeamStructure",
        "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
        "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
        "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    ); // 475
} else if (hasRequestedVersion) {
    // if we've detected an acceptable version
    // embed the Flash Content SWF when all tests are passed
    AC_FL_RunContent(
            "src", "TeamStructure",
            "width", "800",
            "height", "540",
            "align", "middle",
            "id", "Bedrukt-web",
            "quality", "high",
            "bgcolor", "#FFFFFF",
            "name", "Bedrukt-web",
            "allowScriptAccess","sameDomain",
            "type", "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            "pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
    );
  } else {  // flash is too old or we can't detect the plugin
    var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here. '
      + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
       + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
    document.write(alternateContent);  // insert non-flash content
  }
// -->
</script>

<noscript>

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
           codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab"
           id="TeamStructure" width="800" height="475">

    <param name="movie" value="TeamStructure.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--[if !IE]> <-->
    <object data="TeamStructure.swf"
            width="800" height="475" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" align="middle">
        <param name="name" value="Bedrukt-web" />
        <param name="movie" value="TeamStructure.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
    <!--> <![endif]-->
</object>
</noscript>
</div>
```